# iOS/Objective-C: Is there any way to see what localNotifications are scheduled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am trying to get local notifications to work based on times.  I have created an instance of localNotification but am simultaneously trying to get times and dates right while creating the local notifications.

For debugging purposes, is there a way to see what local notifications are scheduled?

I've tried the following but don't see anything firing:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNotification];
 scheduled++;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:reminderNotification];
 scheduled++;
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]
```

will return an array of existing notification instances.